# How to extract p class from the html source code in python (web scraping)?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried to extract telephone number from the below "p class" html source, I am able to extract entire chunck of text with duplicates. Can someone help how to extract just telephone number without duplicates Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
Telefone = soup.find_all('a', class_='it')
Telefone
```

Output:

```
<a class="it" href="tel:+4952531717">0 52 53 / 17 17</a>,
<a class="it" href="tel:+4952531717">0 52 53 / 17 17</a>,
```

"p class" from html source:

```
 <p class="mt-3">Telefon: <a href="tel:+4952536565" class="it">0 52 53 / 65 65</a></p>
```

Full source:

```
 </div>
 <div class="card-body px-1"><!--  panel-body - einzelne Eintrag anfang   -->
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-5">
 <strong><a href="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/Suche_SN/index.js?a=DD&amp;sid=&amp;e_id=793091&amp;Db=" style="text-decoration:underline;" title="Details zum Eintrag ansehen">Frau Dr. med. Birgit Stecher</a></strong>
 <br/><span style="color:#666;">Praktische Ärztin</span>
 <!--  ********
 
 <br /><br><span>Praxis jetzt geschlossen</span>
 
 
 <p class="mt-3">Telefon: <a href="tel:+4952536565" class="it">0 52 53 / 65 65</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why there would be a duplicate as there is only one instance of the href tag with a class of "it" in your example source. I'm unclear if you're trying to extract the "0 52 53 / 65 65" or the "tel:+4952536565" but in both cases you could do:

```
telefone = soup.find('a', class_='it').get_text()
# 0 52 53 / 65 65
```

or

```
telefone = str(soup.find('a', class_='it').get('href'))[5:]  # str()[5:] gets rid of the tel:+
# 4952536565
```